# Can I merge a font-family in CSS to have more font varians via @font-face?

Tags: css, fonts

I have this code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_Casper';
    src: url('fonts/Casper.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('styles/casper/Casper.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Casper.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Casper.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_Casper Italic';
    src: url('fonts/Casper Italic.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('styles/casper/Casper Italic.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Casper Italic.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Casper Italic.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_Casper Bold';
    src: url('fonts/Casper Bold.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('styles/casper/Casper Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Casper Bold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Casper Bold.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_Casper Bold Italic';
    src: url('fonts/Casper Bold Italic.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('styles/casper/Casper Bold Italic.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Casper Bold Italic.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Casper Bold Italic.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

it's the same "font", but it change due to the weight/style. Can I merge those style in one font-family?

Comment: surely now you can just call `font-family: 'Conv_Casper Bold/Italic';` for example.. I have never seen merging of font-face before, so I do believe it is not possible. But i'll wait and see what others have to say.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that you can, this is from the [W3 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule):

> These descriptors define the characteristics of a font face and are
>   used in the process of matching styles to specific faces. For a font
>   family defined with several @font-face rules, user agents can either
>   download all faces in the family or use these descriptors to
>   selectively download font faces that match actual styles used in
>   document. The values for these descriptors are the same as those for
>   the corresponding font properties except that relative keywords are
>   not allowed, ‘bolder’ and ‘lighter’. If these descriptors are omitted,
>   default values are assumed.

Take a look at this example from Google Fonts:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: local('Open Sans Semibold'), local('OpenSans-Semibold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSnhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light Italic'), local('OpenSansLight-Italic'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/PRmiXeptR36kaC0GEAetxh_xHqYgAV9Bl_ZQbYUxnQU.woff) format('woff');
}
```

A usage example:

```
.will-use-the-first-font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.will-use-the-second-font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.will-use-the-third-font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: it rocks as well! Thank you!

Comment: This the logical way to use font faces that constitute a font family, and the way intended in the specs. However, browsers may still fail to honor it, and the method described in the question may work better for some combinations of font, typeface, and browser. Usually bold (weight 400) and italic and bold italic work OK, but there can be problems with other typefaces. Careful testing on different browsers is advisable.